# find and replace a value in a configuration file

Tags: powershell

I have a configuration file with the following format:

```
INSTANCENAME="test"
INSTANCEID="oraID"
USERNAME="gda"
PASSWORD="password"
HOSTNAME="ht.gda.com"
```

With a PowerShell script I want to find an replace some values in this configuration file. Lets say I have a variable:

```psh
$username="cana"
```

I need find and replace that in configuration file. So finally in configuration file I need to have:

```
INSTANCENAME="test"
INSTANCEID="oraID"
USERNAME="cana"
PASSWORD="password"
HOSTNAME="ht.gda.com"
```

Comment: Is there any approach you have tried that we can help you with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```psh
$cfg = 'C:\path\to\config.txt'
(Get-Content $cfg -Raw) -replace 'USERNAME=".*?"', "USERNAME=`"$username`"" |
  Set-Content $cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me:

```
$iniFile="c:\config.ini"
$new="cana"
(get-content $iniFile -raw) -replace "USERNAME="".*?""", "USERNAME=""$new""" | set-content $iniFile
```